# Can you show cell output at the right tab in Google Colab?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

Is it possible to view cell output at the right tab, when viewing 2 tabs in 2 columns?
Is it possible to view code at the left tab and the output at the right tab, as in the below picture?
[image]

Answer (score 3):

It is not exactly what you want but it could help someone else,

if you add to the top of you div the header :

```
#@title { vertical-output: true}
```

you get :

[image: vertical output notebook]

Answer (score 0):

Officially in colab it is not possible but with the help of extension, it will possible.

you can go with this post for download/how to install/ how to use: [enter link description here](https://www.reddit.com/r/GoogleColab/comments/pp9x2c/inputoutput_cells_side_by_side/)